# Помогите новичку в debian настроить источники пакетов

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Уважаемые господа,

я никогда в жизни не видел debian, всегда пользовался ubuntu.

И привык, что после установки системы до состояния, когда туда можно за-ssh-иться, там все более-менее на месте. А если мне не хватает, например, `curl`'а - я пишу

```
    apt install curl
```

и можно хлопать в ладоши.

Первый раз в жизни, по необходимости, поставил debian. Столкнулся с тем, что общего, уже настроенного источника пакетов в системе нет. (возможно, это зависит от дистрибутива)

Мой файл  `/etc/apt/sources.list` - такой:

```
    deb https://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib
    deb-src https://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib

    deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib
    deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib
```

Как бы мне добавить туда источник пакетов, чтобы можно было ставить разные штуки типа curl, docker и т.п.?

Зарнее спасибо!

Comment: «общего, уже настроенного источника пакетов в системе нет» — значит вы что-то сломали, потому что по умолчанию он всегда есть

Comment: у удалил "cdrom" как источник пакетов... возможно, он был по умолчанию, но тогда это как то всё равно крайне непривычно

Comment: Ставлю деибан в виртуалку — после установки базовой системы установщик [предлагает выбрать источник пакетов](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSY9O.png)

Comment: После завершения установки в sources.list [всё прописано как надо и curl тоже есть](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCmoV.png) — наверно вы что-то где-то всё-таки сломали

Comment: Спасибо, прошу прощения за твердолобость, сейчас попробую еще раз. Поставлю с нуля дебиан, возможно, я где то пропустил выбор источника пакетов

Comment: Ну не знаю, я даже не увидел, где его вообще можно было бы пропустить) Возможно, у вас в процессе установки не было интернета? Или, может, вы с какого-то нестандартного образа устанавливаетесь?

Comment: При установке без интернета установщик [предлагает продолжить без источника пакетов](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDxm7.png) — возможно, вы случайно прокликали это окно и не заметили?

Comment: Да, я нашел это окно. Просто там так хитро сфрмулирован вопрос, и к нему как то приплетена GUI самого debian'а - я действительно в первый раз его пропустил. То есть, ответил по умолчанию. А по умолчанию там - "No" - в смысле, "я не хочу использовать источник пакетов"

Comment: Да уж, установщик убунты намного дружелюбнее)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уважаемый  **andreymal** направил меня в нужную сторону.

Конечно, я пропустил конфигурацию источника пакетов при установке.

Но, в своё оправдание, я скажу вот что. Чуть ниже - это злополучное окно, которое я пропустил.

Вчитайтесь, как иезуитски-каверзно сформулирован вопрос.

По умолчанию выбрано "No".

Написано "use of a mirror is suggested if you plan to install a graphical desktop environment".

Ну, так я не собирался ставить GDE. И сказал No. Ну даже не сказал, оставил "как было".

[image: debian]

А надо было выбрать Yes, тогда там можно сконфигурировать, с какого именно зеркала "черпать" обновления.

Кстати, интересно, что на последнем шаге, перед перезагрузкой, можно вернуться на разные шаги инсталляции системы. На разные. Можно выбрать, какой софт ставить 0 ну, там , веб - сервера и т.п. Можно изменить место установки GRUB.

А вот как вернуться на этот шаг, на котором я лоханулся - я здесь не нашел.

[image: end-of-debian-install]

Comment: господа, если Вы хотите мне помочь - напигшите, пожалуйста, какие у Вас в свежем дебиане источники пакетов. Потому что я первый раз в жизни поставил эту систему. и не могу понять, черт побери, почему она такая недружелюбная после убунты. Конечно, если бы я мог выбирать - я бы никогда не стал связываться, так и сидел бы себе на убунте. Но мне пришлось. я не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы debian брал пакеты из сети. я просмотрел пару страниц ссылок в гугле, но они мне не помогли

Comment: Вот прям заинтриговали. Можете линк на дистрибутив с которого ставите кинуть? Сколько ставил никогда проблем не встречал

Comment: я Вам могу скинуть, но я - сам дурак. я пропустил очевидную вещь. там нет никакой проблемы, просто я её случайно сам себе создал. Так что, мне кажется, вопрос закрыт :-) Спасибо, хоть, не закидали с самого начала ссаными тряпками :-)